# MYSQL - SELECT all rows, but use Distinct on one column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, rows

I have a table data like this

```
Column_a  | Column_b
  a       |    5
  b       |    25
  g       |    14
  t       |    13
  b       |    15
  c       |    04
  g       |    15
  b       |    13
```

in the column_a i have a lot of duplicate values, i want to be able to select all the rows from the table but if two rows have the same column_a value, i want only the row with the biggest value from colum_b in the results
exemple of the result that i am looking for :

```
Column_a  | Column_b
  a       |    5
  b       |    25
  t       |    13
  c       |    04
  g       |    15
```

## Thank you in advance

**

1. Update of the question

**

these are the columns i have in my table :
CRMID | user |  ticket_id | |  description  |  date | hour

what i am trying to do is to select all the rows from the table, but when two rows have the same ticket_id, i want only the newest one to appear in the results, so the row with the newest date and hour ,
Sorry for making this such complicated !
i am not a native english speaker and i find it hard to well explain the problem.

Comment: You want to use `group by`.  And you want to study the SQL language a bit if you are going to be using it.

Comment: i faced a problem with this, it selects only the column_b with the highest value, its doesn't show all the rows. i have more than two columns in my table

Answer (score 4):

If you group by `column_a` then you can use aggregate functions like `max()` on it to get the maximum value of each group

```
select column_a, 
       max(column_b) as column_b
from your_table
group by column_a
```

Comment: Thank you juergen, i totally forgot about max(), :3 thank you again

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Column_A, MAX(Column_B) FROM table
GROUP BY Column_A
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a `Group By` clause.  Your syntax should look similar to this:

```
SELECT Column_A, MAX(Column_B) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Column_A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the columns in the table, then you have a different problem (and one not in the original posting).  One reason you should add code into such a question is so you get a broader range of answers.  I, for one, ignored the question, thinking it was just a newbie asking about obvious SQL functionality.

In MySQL the best approach is to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.column_a = t.column_a and
                        t2.column_b > t.column_b
                 );
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `table(column_a, column_b)`.  Also, this can return multiple rows, if there are duplicated maximum values.

This query is not intuitive.  What it is doing is:  "Get me all rows from the table where there is no other row with the same `column_a` value and a higher `column_b` value".  If you think about it, this is the same as getting the maximum value.  This has better performance than other methods (notably, aggregation and join), because MySQL does a simple index lookup for each row in the table.  That is faster than aggregation and join.

Comment: Thank you so much gordan for your answer, i tried to use what you have mentioned but it didn't work, i'm afraid i miss-used it, i added an update to my question explaining my case :/

Comment: it's okay, i added a timestamp fields, to make it easyer, and this is my query (based on what you teached me ^^)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t.ticket_id, t.id
FROM tickets t
WHERE NOT
EXISTS (

SELECT 1
FROM tickets t1
WHERE t.timestampp < t1.timestampp
AND t.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
)

Comment: Thank you so much gordon

Answer (score -1):

select * from (select * from yourtable order by column_b desc)t group by column_a